# How to send values that are not related to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a `Post` model that have a `title` and `content` attributes.

I want to make it possible to tweet when the user creates a post like this.

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.check_box :with_tweet %> # Error
  <%= f.text_field :tweet %> # Error
<% end %>
```

This code fails, because there are no `with_tweet` and `tweet` attributes for `Post`.
I don't think query strings are good idea situation like this.

How should I send a information that is not related a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define them as virtual attributes:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessor :with_tweet, :tweet
  ...
end
```

`attr_accessor` will provide a getter and a setter method for `with_tweet` and `tweet` which should then be accessible to you through the `@post` object.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Vee's answer, let me explain why you'd need it:

> Every `attribute` in a Rails model is the result of using a [Ruby
>   getter & setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281215/ruby-rails-understanding-ruby-getter-setter-methods-and-instances) - meaning that your model's attributes are
>   essentially just parts of a Ruby object, built when your class is
>   initialized
>
> The problem you have is Ruby on Rails does not build any other
>   attributes other than the ones in your DB, meaning if you wanted to
>   track extra data, you'll have to use [`virtual attributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109118/virtual-attributes-in-rails-4) to let
>   the class know to populate those not in the db
>
> [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails) is used to define those extra attributes